# What is the difference between readable property method and a callable function that is just returns the data as a property can?

Tags: python

I have a property that returns list of names with "ash" in it

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filter_key = ""
        self.name = ""

    def filter_names(self, filter_key):
        self.filter_key = filter_key

    @property
    def student_names(self):
        return self.names

    def callable_function_names(self):
        return names
```

and then student class that inherits BaseClass

```
class StudentClass(BaseClass):

     @property
     def student_names(self):
         names = super(StudentClass, self).student_names
         return [name for name in names if self.filter_students in name]

     @property
     def filter_key(self):
        """Gets """
        return self.filter_key

     @slot_key.setter
     def filter_key(self, key):
        """Sets name filter"""
        self.filter_names(key)

    # or by doing :

     def callable_function_names(self):
         names = super(StudentClass, self).callable_function_names()
         return [name for name in names if self.filter_students in name]
```

So if I create obj of the student class.

```
studentclsObj = StudentClass()
studentclsObj.filter_key = "ash"

print studentclsObj.student_names 
print studentclsObj.callable_function_names()
```

I can achieve the same result with both above prints, is there any difference and what is preferred and right way to do ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? The difference is that the property is used as if it were an attribute.

Comment: Take note that your code does not work - you never define the self.name and name variables used by the BaseClass methods, nor self.filter_timeline_tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use case of properties is not breaking API. This is one of main strengths of python IMO. You can take a function, make transform it in a callable object, add new functionality without breaking old code, now the property

I see three main uses of properties over attributes,

## Read only attributes

Is easy to create read only attributes with properties. They are non verbose, self documenting and simple

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, bar):
      self._bar = bar

   @property
   def bar(self):
      return self._bar
```

## Validation on writable properties

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, bar):
       self._bar = bar

   @property
   def bar(self):
       return self._bar

   @bar.setter
   def bar(self, val):
       if valid(val):
            self._bar = val
```

This is a kind of defensive programming

## Keep API compatibility

Imagine that you have a class for a bank account, with
a balance property

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0
```

You have this code and it works fine. But know your client
says, I need you to log every balance lookup. You can replace
the attribute by a property without breaking old code

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self._balance = 0

    @property
    def balance(self):
        self.log_balance_read()
        return self._balance
```

There is no difference between a property and a method which return the same value. Go for the simpler, use method for actions and state changes and attributes for real attributes, if you need to add logic to attribute lookup, python will let you do it